# How to declare a DAO variable using an interface but put in it a concrete implementation in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

I am studying how to integrate Spring Framework with Hibernate and I have some doubt about it.

I have develop a personal example that work well but I am not sure about the architecture of this project.

So I have an interface named **PersonDAO** in wich I have declared the CRUD operation that I would in my DAO

Then I have created a concrete implementation of this interface by the class **PersonDAOImpl** that implement the previous interface.

Then I have create the following main class to test my dao object:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAOImpl;
import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

public static void main( String[] args ){

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    System.out.println("Contesto recuperato: " + context);

    Person persona1 = new Person();

    persona1.setFirstname("Pippo");
    persona1.setLastname("Blabla");
    persona1.setPid(1);

    System.out.println("Creato persona1: " + persona1);

    PersonDAOImpl dao = (PersonDAOImpl) context.getBean("personDAOImpl");

    System.out.println("Creato dao object: " + dao);

    dao.addPerson(persona1);

    System.out.println("persona1 salvata nel database");

}
```

}

The DAO work well and my object is correctly persisted on my database but I have the following architectural doubt: **Why have I an interface if I am not using it?**

Finnally, in this way, I could not have the interface and use directly the concrete class...

I think that, architecturally, this is so bad...

I have try to change my **App.java** clas and try to use the DAO object in this way:

```
PersonDAO dao = (PersonDAO) context.getBean("personDAOImpl");
```

but don't work...

In this tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/

there is an other situation, that really use the interface, in witch there is a **ContactServiceImpl** class in witch I have the **ContactDAO** variable declared using the **@Autowired** annotation:

```
@Autowired
private ContactDAO contactDAO;
```

**ContactDAO** is a DAO **interface** but Spring autowire an object that is an istance of it's implemtantio **ContactDAOImpl** (that is annoted using @Repository)

So, using the **@Autowired annotation, in this code I can declare a variable using an interface but put in this variable the reference to a concrete implementation of it !!!

In my project I don't use the annotion bean configuration mechanism but I am using the XML configuration mechanism...but I think that also in this case I can do somenthing like it...

I my project XML configuration file I have declared my bean like this:

```
<bean id="personDAOImpl" class="org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAOImpl" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

What can I do to declare my dao variable as an interface and put in it a concrete implementation of it? (still using XML configuration)

This is the **stack trace error** that I have when I use:

```
    PersonDAO dao = (PersonDAO) context.getBean("personDAOImpl");
```

in my App.Java test class

**INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@7363c839] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Contesto recuperato: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@591f5ff9: startup date [Sat Feb 23 11:42:25 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchyException in thread "main" 
Creato persona1: org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person@23653628
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAOImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d46b3a86 cannot be cast to org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAO
    at org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.App.main(App.java:27)**

Tnx
Andrea

Comment: HOW does it not work. It MUST work if the first one works, since PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO. Paste the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: ok, posted in the original post

Comment: I don't get what you don't understand. Loose coupling architectural principal? The (short) idea behind is that classes contain a reference to an interface say, `PersonDAO`, and you *inject* a concrete implementation via Spring (that you delcare with annotation `@Autowired`, or as a property in xml.

Comment: Show us the code of PersonDAOImpl. My guess is that it simply doesn't implement PersonDAO, or that it implements another interface.

Comment: @skuntsel My question is about the followint thing: if I use Autowired annotation I preserve polimorfism and I can declare PersonDAO variable and have in it the reference to an it's implementation...
But if I use XML configuration I have not polimorfism and I have to declare the variable with it's concrete type

I am asking you if, using XML configuration is it possible to preserve polymorfism

Comment: @JBNizet Ok...I am STUPID !!! I have forgot to implement the interface in my concrete class !!! Ok...no comment... :-/

Comment: `@Autowired` has no relation to polymorphism. It has relation to dependency injection, as well as the xml configuration is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very essence of interface and concrete implementation is to preserve polymorphism. In a testing environment you could use a different concrete implementation but same interface, while in developing mode another implementation could be put in the xml configuration. It would be easily for you to swap xml configurations without changing the java code like swapping from developing to testing environment or another tester would use your same code but with different xml configurations.

if you are going to use directly the implementation in the xml, then you will lose the power of polymorphism, and would need to change the java code if you have to swap to a different implementation.

Your PersonDAOImpl must implement PersonDAO, such as

```
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO
```

Xml configuration is only use for dependency injection or singleton bean instances across the application, it doesn't have anything to do with preserving polymorphism. What you have to do is to follow the interface-implementation of java.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code for PersonDAOImpl? it must implement PersonDAO interface